# Trouble with code ( adding datetime.strftime wehn exporting data frame to the name path of new excel )

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I've been trying to add to the file name the date when exporting a dataframe to excel. But instead to creating the excel file, it is searching for a file with that name instead of creating a file with that name.

'''python

```
     datestring= datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%m/%d/%Y')
     export_excel=df_vacias.to_excel(r"the path {0}".format("vacias_" 
     datestring +'.xlsx',index=None, header=True))
```

Error

```
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\(the user)\\Desktop\\vacias_09/19/2019.xlsx'
```

I expect the creation of this file 'C:\Users\(the user)\Desktop\vacias_09/19/2019.xlsx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like many special characters, `/` character is also not allowed to be in a file or folder name in Windows. I think that's your problem.